# debootstrap error in Ubuntu 13.04 raring

Tags: ubuntu, debootstrap

I'm trying to create a file system in Ubuntu with the command:

```
sudo debootstrap --foreign --no-check-gpg --include=ca-certificates --arch=armhf testing rootfs http://debian.raspbian.com/debian
```

but it got the following error:

```
/usr/sbin/debootstrap: 1294: /usr/sbin/debootstrap: cannot create /home/.../rootfs/test-dev-null: Permission denied
E: Cannot install into target '/home/.../rootfs' mounted with noexec or nodev
```

can anyone help me here? Thanks!

Comment: What are the permissions on `rootfs`?

Answer (score 7):

Find out which filesystem the path `/home/.../rootfs` resides in (might be a dedicated partition or an LVM, you don't give specifics), and, as root (or using `sudo`) remount it with `exec` and `dev` options.

```
# mount -o remount,exec,dev /home
```

Here, `/home` is an example that assumes a separated partition or dedicated logical volume.

Answer (score 2):

Remounting with `exec` and `dev` is the solution. If your filesystem is **encrypted**, you also need to pass `-i` to mount.

```
 $ sudo mount -i -o remount,exec,dev /home/user
```

Where in my case `/home/user/` is my encrypted home directory. After that debootstrap had no issues any more.